# Two queries in one nested sql query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to make the two sql statement as one.
First one shows total order placed daily and second one shows only the count of orders having staff as action text daily.

```
select date(dated) date_ord, count(*) as orders_placed
from stats.sales_actions 
group by date_ord 
order by dated desc

select date(dated) date_order, count(*) as orders_modified
from stats.sales_actions 
where action_text LIKE '%STAFF%'
group by date_ord 
order by dated desc
```

I want to show in one table/sql query if possible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select date(dated) date_ord, 
count(*) as orders_placed, 
SUM (
        CASE 
           WHEN action_text LIKE '%STAFF%' 
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ORDERS_STAFF 
from stats.sales_actions 
group by date_ord 
order by dated desc
```

This shows both values on one row. If you like it in 2 lines, just use union between the queries.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thank you! I'm heading in direction 100 rep ;-)!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `UNION`:

```
select date(dated) date_ord, count(*), 'orders_places' as orders_placed
from stats.sales_actions 
group by date_ord 
order by dated desc
UNION
select date(dated) date_order, count(*), 'orders_modified' as orders_modified
from stats.sales_actions 
where action_text LIKE '%STAFF%'
group by date_ord 
order by dated desc
```

Comment: the one problem with the union is they will not know which item is orders_placed or orders_modified since it will have the same column name. you would have to include something to distinguish them.

Comment: @bluefeet you can add another column like I stated now.

Comment: simple and effective solution

Comment: @rachel, if you don't need it, you don't put it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION to achieve this - you can then give the count colums a name using the AS keyword to distinguish them from one another. For example:

```
select date(dated) date_ord, count(*) AS placed, 'orders_places' as orders_placed
from stats.sales_actions 
group by date_ord 
order by dated desc
UNION
select date(dated) date_order, count(*) AS modified, orders_modified' as orders_modified
from stats.sales_actions 
where action_text LIKE '%STAFF%'
group by date_ord 
order by dated desc
```

Comment: Sure, it's actually a very simple change from the two queries you had. I just copied and pasted your queries, put UNION (which essentially pulls the two queries together into one result table in this case) in to group the two of them, and then named your count(*) columns since if I hadn't they would share the same name. You can do this using the AS keyword - `[column_to_select] AS name` - this would give the column named "column_to_select" the name "name" in your result.

Answer (score 1):

```
select   date_ord, sum( orders_placed) as orders_placed ,   
          sum( orders_modified) as orders_modified
   from( 

            select date(dated) date_ord, count(*) as orders_placed , 0 as orders_modified
            from stats.sales_actions 
            group by date_ord 
            order by dated desc

           UNION

            select date(dated) date_ord, 0 as orders_placed, count(*)  as orders_modified
            from stats.sales_actions 
            where action_text LIKE '%STAFF%'
            group by date_ord 
            order by dated desc
        ) temp
          group by date_ord 
          order by dated desc
```